# Next/previous placeholder or one word right/left not working as expected in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

When using "*Next placeholder or one word right*" (`ctrl + →`) or "*Previous placeholder or one word left*" (`ctrl+ ←`) in TexStudio, it is not working as expected. It occurs with the following line:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Abstract %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

For explaining purposes I am using some indicators to make the explanation easier to understand, meaning that the numbers `<1>` to `<5>` are not there in practice.

```
<1>
<2>%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <3>Abstract <4>%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<5>
```

If I place the pointer at <3> and jump to the right (`ctrl + →`) then it jumps to <5> and not to <4>. It's the same vice versa, so if the pointer is at <5> and I jump to the left, it jumps to <3> instead of <4>. Furthermore, if I jump from <3> to the left, it jumps to <1> (the end of the previous line) instead of <2> (the start of the current line)

I looked online but could not find anything on the subject, I also looked through the settings but did not find an option to alter this behavior. Any idea on how to change this behavior and if it is even possible?

Comment: I can confirm your problem on macOS, texstudio 2.12.22 hence I opened an issue under TeXstudio's bug tracker: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1130.